# TypeError while working with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Nokogiri returns me a page of code:

```
<a href="/yakutsk/search/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C/rubricId/7036994676850915/tab/firms?queryState=zoom%2F11" class="link _scheme_none rubricsList__listItemLinkTitle">Скорая медицинская помощь</a>
<a href="/yakutsk/search/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8/rubricId/7036994676850839/tab/firms?queryState=zoom%2F11" class="link _scheme_none rubricsList__listItemLinkTitle">Справочно-информационные услуги</a>
<a href="/yakutsk/search/%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B/rubricId/7036994676850810/tab/firms?queryState=zoom%2F11" class="link _scheme_none rubricsList__listItemLinkTitle">Аварийные службы</a>
<a href="/yakutsk/search/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%93%D0%9E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%A7%D0%A1/rubricId/7036994676851395/tab/firms?queryState=zoom%2F11" class="link _scheme_none rubricsList__listItemLinkTitle">Управление ГО и ЧС</a>
```

As you see there only links with hrefs. And I want get it href content.
And if I try to do so:

```
data1 = data.css("li")
data2 = data1.css("a")

puts data2["href"]
```

I got an error:

```
test.rb:93:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Why? Sure I can get href content with simple RegExp. But there is a simple way I see.

Comment: `css` returns a `NodeSet`, i.e. multiple nodes. Therefore, [`NodeSet#[]`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet#%5B%5D-instance_method) works like [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) – it expects an index, not a string.

Comment: There is no `<li>` in your sample. Please make sure your question is correct. As @Stefan says, `#css` returns a list of nodes, `#at_css` returns the first encountered node.

Comment: There was <li> before I make data1 = data.css("li")

Comment: Then fix your question so it's consistent. Please read "[mcve]". Your code needs to match the data otherwise you're injecting confusion into your question reducing its value.

Comment: You don't want to dip into using regular expressions to parse HTML or XML. They're too free-form and flexible to be used on anything but the most simple markup. Code written to do so is very fragile, whereas using a parser it will be much more resilient.

Answer (score 1):

When I added:

```
data2.each { |x|
      puts x["href"]
}
```

I got the results. Simple. Too simple.